# How to get table id using Row

Tags: jquery

I have two tables like this,

```
<table id="table1">
    <tr RowID="1">
        <td>1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr RowID="2">
        <td>2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table id="table2">
    <tr RowID="3">
        <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr RowID="4">
        <td>4</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var rowID = 4;
    $("tr[RowID='" + rowID + "']")  //Here I need to Get table's ID
});
```

IS there any way I can get above row's table's id

http://jsfiddle.net/customizedName/YK8w4/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) to get the closest ancestor element matching the given selector

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var rowID = 4;
    var id = $("tr[RowID='" + rowID + "']").closest('table').attr('id');
    alert(id)
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/T5k6T/)

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var rowID = 4;
    $("tr[RowID='" + rowID + "']")  //Here I need to Get table's ID
    $("tr[RowID='" + rowID + "']").closest("table").attr("id");  //this should do it
});
```

`closest` will get the closest parent matching the selector.  From there you can grab the id.

Here's a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/YK8w4/1/

Answer (score 1):

You can use [closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) to traverse up the DOM tree from your `tr` with id named `RowID4` to get the first matched table which is table with id `table2`. Then you can use [attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) or [prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) to get the `id`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var rowID = 4;
    var id = $("tr[RowID='" + rowID + "']").closest('table').attr('id'); // or .prop('id')
    console.log(id);
});
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7DRMg/1/)**